# How Do I Use NAudio In A Visual Basic Application

Tags: naudio

I'm trying to play audio from a Microsoft Visual Basic application I'm creaeting using Visual Studio Pro 2022.

I'm currently using WMPLib to playback audio.  Although it works, I'm looking for a more elegant way of making this happen.

After making some inquiries, someone told me about NAudio.  Can NAudio perform the following tasks?
a.  Play an audio file (Wav)
b.  Stop an audio file (Wav)
c.  Allow me to control the volume of the playback.
d.  Provide two states: 1) Audio Playing and 2) Audio not playing.

Comment: The solution can be C# or Visual Basic.